# Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/cram width'

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, pgfkeys

I'm trying to draw the D-glucopyranose using the `chemfig` package, so I copied the piece of code from chemfig manual:

```
\chemfig[cram width=2pt]{HO-[2,0.5,2]?<[7,0.7](-[2,0.5]OH)-[,,,,line width=2pt](-[6,0.5]OH)>[1,0.7](-[6,0.5]OH)-[3,0.7]O-[4]?(-[2,0.3]-[3,0.5]OH)}
```

Even if i put `\usepackage{chemfig}` in the preamble, latex still gives me the same error:

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key `/tikz/cram width`

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig[cram width=2pt]{HO-[2,0.5,2]?<[7,0.7](-[2,0.5]OH)-[,,,,line width=2pt](-[6,0.5]OH)>[1,0.7](-[6,0.5]OH)-[3,0.7]O-[4]?(-[2,0.3]-[3,0.5]OH)}

\end{document}` should work perfectly fine. Which version of the `chemfig` package so you use?

Comment: I don't know, but also with this code, I get the same error. Actually I don't know which version of the package chemfig I'm using.

Comment: When you go to a command prompt and type `texdoc chemfig` (followed by enter) then you get the package manual for the version that is installed on your system, the version is mentioned on the title page. Alternatively you can check the log file (also for example in Overleaf, where you don't have a command prompt), the packages with versions are listed near the top.

Comment: Thank you, now I can see that I have chemfig 1.2e installed

Comment: But latex shows me the same error

Comment: @SimoneCervellati: The latest version of `chemfig` is `1.41`. Which this version, the code from my previous comment works. Could you try to update?

Comment: I tried to look for some way to do it on Google, but I couldn't find anything useful. Can you help me?

Comment: That depends on how you have installed LaTeX. If you use Windows and MikTeX then you can use the MikTeX package manager. If you use MacTeX or TeX Live on Mac then you can use `tlmgr`. If you use vanilla TeX Live (installed via a download from the TeX Live website) on Linux then you can also use `tlmgr`. If you installed on Linux with a distribution package then you need to do a manual update. However, a quick solution is to download http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig.sty and put that in the same folder as your `.tex` file, with some luck that will solve the issue.

Comment: Note that that is not really the best solution, because if you compile another document in another folder then it will use the old version again (unless you copy the new file also there). A proper update with a package manager (or manually copying the files to the appropriate system directory) ensures that all your documents will use the updated package.